# Combination of columns as table's primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to make a combination of columns a table's primary key?

For example I have:

`ID_1  |  ID_2  | ID_3   |  ID_4  | VALUE 
-----   ------  ------   ------   ------
  1        1      1         1        A 
  1        2      1         1        B 
  2        1      1         1        A`

I want the values of ID_1, ID_2, ID_3 and ID_4 combined to be the primary key.
Thanks

Comment: Yes. Just include all the columns when you define your primary key, e.g. `CREATE TABLE T (ID_1 INT .... PRIMARY KEY(ID_1, ID_2, ID_3, ID_4));`

Comment: fyi, they are called compound primary keys

Comment: What's the difference between composite key? or compound primary key is for SQL and composite is for MySQL?

Comment: No difference, they are synonym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-First solution:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName (    
       id_1 INT NOT NULL,
       id_2 INT NOT NULL,
       id_3 INT NOT NULL,
       id_4 INT NOT NULL,
       value VARCHAR(10) NULL,
       CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (id_1, id_2, id_3, id_4)
    );
```

-Second solution: 
Use association tables.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but should be avoided. Primary key should be one column.

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`new_table` (
  `id_1` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_2` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_3` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_4` INT NOT NULL,
  `value` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_1`, `id_2`, `id_3`, `id_4`));
```

Comment: Why should it be avoided? I am torn between upvoting for the correct create table syntax, or downvoting for the nonsense that precedes it.

Comment: It makes a code more complicated, when trying to work with that table. For example auto incrementing PK.

Comment: re avoidance, it really depends on the use case and data.

Comment: For what reason it must be avoided? What you mean by incrementing PK? From OP's code it's evident that he is not using synthetic key column.

Comment: Suppose tabla A has composite pk (4 cols). another table B has FK which links to A. How B's FK will look like? Your database, your queries will look comlicated.