# MySQL UNIQUE on a combination of columns

Tags: mysql, combinations, permutation, unique-constraint

Consider the case where I have a table with players data and a table where I want to store matches in a tournament. Say each match has 3 players and what I want to achieve is uniqueness of the three players, no matter in what order they were picked.

```
match_id | id_player_1 | id_player_2 | id_player 3 | other_columns
   1     |      1      |      2      |     3       | .....         
   2     |      2      |      1      |     4       | .....         
   3     |      3      |      1      |     2       | .....         NOT OK
   4     |      1      |      4      |     3       | .....
```

match 1 and 3 are, in my tournament, not possible as they have the same players.
In MySQL if I create a UNIQUE constraint on the triple id_player_1, id_player_2, id_player_3 it won't trigger a problem with the insertion of match 3 after match 1.

Is there a workaround?

Not sure if this applies to my case:
[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460453/combination-of-columns-as-tables-primary-key)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique combination of 2 columns, order independent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61856192/unique-combination-of-2-columns-order-independent)

Comment: You might want to consider saving the player-match-association in a separated table, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Denormalized structure produces problems. Pay attention to Bill's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to store the match player as a set of rows, with one player per row, instead of a single row as you are doing now.

```
CREATE TABLE match_players (
  match_id INT NOT NULL,
  id_player INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (match_id, id_player)
)

INSERT INTO match_players VALUES 
  (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3),
  (2, 2), (2, 1), (1, 4),
  (3, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2),
  (4, 1), (4, 4), (4, 3);
```

It doesn't matter which order you list these tuples, the uniqueness of players in each match is still enforced.

SQL is most powerful when you think of data in sets.